# shell script to add leading zeros in middle of file name

Tags: shell, padding, ksh, leading-zero

I have files with names like "words_transfer1_morewords.txt". I would like to ensure that the number after "transfer" is five digits, as in "words_transfer00001_morewords.txt". How would I do this with a ksh script? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will work in any Bourne-type/POSIX shell as long as your *words* and *morewords* don't contain numbers:

```
file=words_transfer1_morewords.txt
prefix=${file%%[0-9]*}   # words_transfer
suffix=${file##*[0-9]}   # _morewords.txt
num=${file#$prefix}      # 1_morewords.txt
num=${num%$suffix}       # 1
file=$(printf "%s%05d%s" "$prefix" "$num" "$suffix")
echo "$file"
```

Comment: Hmm.. are you sure about the parameter expansion/substring extraction being POSIX?? Bash - yes, Bourne - ??

Comment: `%` and `#` are both POSIX (which is orthogonal to the question of whether they are in Bourne). The `bash` extension would be to use `num=${file/%[0-9]*}` to both match and remove the prefix in one operation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, I'm sure. POSIX defines it here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 I work with The Opengroup :-)

Comment: That is the best bit of education I have received in a long time. I don't know why I had that stored as a bashism.

Comment: For me this worked up to the "num=${file#$prefix}" line (I checked by echo-ing after every line). It doesn't find the prefix and just takes the whole filename. Removing the suffix after that works, but $num is wrong because the prefix was never removed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ksh`'s regular expression matching operation to break the filename down into separate parts, them put them back together again after formatting the number.

```
pre="[^[:digit:]]+"  # What to match before the number
num="[[:digit:]]+"   # The number to match
post=".*"            # What to match after the number

[[ $file =~ ($pre)($num)($post) ]]
new_file=$(printf "%s%05d%s\n" "${.sh.match[@]:1:3}")
```

Following a successful match with `=~`, the special array parameter `.sh.match` contains the full match in element 0, and each capture group in order starting with element 1.